# VSTS YAML pipeline - pass project repository as parameter for the existed build definition

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I'd like to pass repository URL ( with tags and branches ) with a project source code to build *as parameter* to YAML build definition ( which resides in another repository ). So I can build various projects ( come from various repositories / tags / branches   ) with the same build definition. Ideally I would also like to parametrize a folder name of the project repository gets cloned to.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you add a file named .vsts-ci.yml to the **root of your repository**. It will create the build pipeline in a folder that has the same name as your repository, and a new build is automatically created and queued.

Even you create a YAML build pipeline manually, you have to select the repo that contains your .YML file. So it doesn't support pass repository URL as parameter to a YAML build definition.

[image]

For your idea, you could consider creating a UserVoice at website below:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/category/145257-dashboards-and-reporting.